# Cannot connect to alternate Mongo DB in Meteor App

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am running a Meteor app. locally using a Virtual Machine (VM). I want to use a new Mongo DB that I have set-up on the VM called 'my_db'. I have set the MONGO_URL on the command line like this:

```
export MONGO_URL='mongodb://127.0.0.1:3001/my-db'
```

I have checked that this environment variable is set using echo $MONGO_URL and I get back:

```
mongodb://127.0.0.1:3001/my-db
```

However, when I start up my Meteor app. it still connects to the default 'meteor' database. Why is this and what can I do to get it connecting to my alternative 'my_db' database?

Comment: env vars used only on builded production stage: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/deploying

Comment: Right, so can you give an answer as to what should be used in development instead?

Comment: As it turns out, I needed to do two things to get this to work, 1) change the port to 27017, 2) change the permissions on my meteor app. (http://www.maxlibin.com/remove-sudo-meteor/)

Answer (score 2):

Like @dr.dimitr say `env vars` are only used on the production process (for example connecting your modulus app with the modulus db they provide or another different), on the developing process you can use the mongo drive like this.

```
if(Meteor.isServer){
    Meteor.startup(function () {
       var myDatabase = new MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver("<mongo url>");
       MyCollection = new Mongo.Collection("collection_name", { _driver: myDatabase });
     });
   }
```

Now you need to know  name of the url `<mongo url>` which could be something like `mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/local` or `meteor`

Some Related Posts - [(1)](https://forums.meteor.com/t/mongointernals-is-not-defined-error/572) and [(2)](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2590)

Comment: When I get round to deploying this app to a remote server which will then rely instead on env vars, what happens to all this surplus code that you have suggested I use?

Comment: Also, the second link above states "This is an internal, undocumented, underscored interface, so use at your own risk." - so should I really be using this?? Meteor must have some database initialization technique that can be used for development AND production - after all, aren't we supposed to be replicating these environments as best practice anyway and, therefore, one technique should not be different from another?

Comment: ALSO, this method does not work with the Account-Base package ans this package auto-published the Users collection and when I try to register a new users in my app, it still writes back to the 'meteor' database, which is not the one I am using - arghhh!!

Comment: This is just for develop stage right? its like reading the FSCollection READMe wich say "don't use it on production" and so many apps use it on production stage, all that code should disappears when you put this app in some cloud service (heroku,modulus,digital) and you should now use the mongoUrl code, also it work like any other normal collection

Comment: What is FSCollection? When you say 'all that code should disappear' do you mean automatically or needs to be taken out prior to moving it to  production?

Comment: it was an example, and no you should remove it and replace it to Exports, when you plan to move it into production just comment that 2 lines of code and replace it with the Mongo EXPORTs

Comment: This is crazy, why isn't there a consistent way to connect to a database other than the default 'meteor' one? Surely this is contrary to best practice of having dev and production environments marry up ?

Comment: On develop stage meteor handle the local connection envioroment for you by running meteor, but on production your meteor app is actually running behind a nodejs wrapper, that answer tue question? Haha

Comment: @JoePrivett i see you are making a new question about this, using the code from this answer, could you please accept or up vote this?

Comment: I am not sure it is correct, hence the new question.

Comment: i just tested an app with the MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver and it works, so you can use the same code develop/production =D

Comment: Can you get it to also work with the Account-Base package package.

Comment: @JoePrivett i don't try that, this is another question, i think the question here was only how to connect 2 collections on the same app in developer/production mode