# Use existing collection in meteor

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, meteor

I am trying to use an existing collection in meteor:

I tried

```
SET MONGO_URL="mongodb://localhost:27017/test2" meteor
```

But that did not work. I modified the example from [www.angular-meteor.com](http://www.angular-meteor.com) :

> server.js

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    var myDatabase = new MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test2");
    MyCollection = new Mongo.Collection("mydata", { _driver: myDatabase }); 
  });
}
```

> app.js

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  angular.module('socially', ['angular-meteor']); 
  angular.module('socially').directive('partiesList', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: 'parties-list.html',
      controllerAs: 'partiesList',
      controller: function($scope, $reactive) {
        $reactive(this).attach($scope);   
        this.helpers({
          parties: () => {
            return MyCollection.findOne({});
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });
}
```

> parties-list.html

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="party in partiesList.parties">
    {{MyCollection.Date}}
    <p>{{MyCollection.name}}</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

> main.html

```
<parties-list></parties-list>
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? I found the answer at [Cannot connect to alternate Mongo DB in Meteor App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29596198/cannot-connect-to-alternate-mongo-db-in-meteor-app?rq=1) but still trying to make the `<ul>` to show something, now it does not show anything and my page is empty.

Comment: Could you comment out that isServer block and try this: % MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/test2 meteor

Comment: @Brendan Turner Tried, but didnt work

Comment: Error message? Has the db 'test2' been created?

Comment: No errors. Yes test2 db exists at localhost mongodb with mydata collection. But generally, is it a correct approach? Or should env variable work as well?

Comment: env is how I use my app in production. Not sure why it's not working. Have you used the mongo shell to ensure there are collections/documents on test2?

Comment: Ok! Yes there are documenta there. Does it work for you, woth some collection of yours?

Comment: It's possible there is just an error with how you're trying to display the documents. Assuming you still have the `autopublish` package installed you can use your web browser's console to see what documents you have access to with `MyCollection.find({}).fetch()`. Also, I think you should revert that startup block to the normal way of declaring a collection.

Comment: Also, you're using `ng-repeat="party in partiesList.parties` but are attempting to display `<p>{{MyCollection.name}}</p>` instead of `<p>{{party.name}}</p>`

Comment: Ok thanks, will test it tonight. Thanks! Maybe post an answer? I guess other ppl are wondering too:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a few problems:

```
      parties: () => {
        return MyCollection.findOne({});
      }
```

This will only return one document, and I assume you want all of them since you're using ngRepeat to iterate over `parties`. This leads me to the next issue:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="party in partiesList.parties">
    {{MyCollection.Date}}
    <p>{{MyCollection.name}}</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

You're iterating over parties with ngRepeat which repeats the `<li>` for each object found within parties and assigns that value to a temporary object `party`. It should look like this:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="party in partiesList.parties">
    {{party.Date}}
    <p>{{party.name}}</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I tried that but still does not work. When I do `MyCollection.find({}).fetch()` in console I get `[]`. That is strange because I know there are documents in `test2` database in `mydata` collection.